# How to select without using CTL key in multiselect in extjs

Tags: multi-select

xtype:"multiselectfield",
fieldLabel:comboData.Label,
allowBlank:false,
labelAlign:"left",
autoScroll:false,
scroll:false,
width:280,
height:80,
store:comboStore,
value:comboData.selectvalue ? comboData.selectvalue : comboData.items[0].value,
displayField:"name",
valueField:"value",

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a combobox and setting multiSelect to true.

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    multiSelect: true,
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The value of the combobox will be an array of valueFields of the items selected.